# Using JSON result from Zippopotam.us for Google maps coordinate

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The code that I made will ask the user to enter an input (any Malaysian Zip code), and the input will fetch a JSON result from Zippopotam.us. Below is my full codes :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment  Lab 3</title>
    <style>
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div #zipdiv, #citydiv, #statediv, #longitudediv, #latitudediv
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

</style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

  $(document).ready( function()
  {
    $("#citydiv").hide();
    $("#statediv").hide();
    $("#longitudediv").hide();
    $("#latitudediv").hide();
    $("#mapdiv").hide();


  });

  // OnKeyDown Function
  $("#zcode").keyup(function() {
    var zip_in = $(this);
    var zip_box = $('#zipdiv');

    if (zip_in.val().length<5)
    {
      zip_box.removeClass('error success');
    }
    else if ( zip_in.val().length>5)
    {
      zip_box.addClass('error').removeClass('success');
    }
    else if ((zip_in.val().length == 5) )
    {

      // Make HTTP Request
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.zippopotam.us/MY/" + zip_in.val(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result, success) {
          // Make the city and state boxes visible
          $('#citydiv').slideDown(200);
          $('#statediv').slideDown(200);
          $('#longitudediv').slideDown(200);
          $('#latitudediv').slideDown(200);


          // Zip Code Records Officially Map to only 1 Primary Location
          places = result['places'][0];
          $("#city").val(places['place name']);
          $("#state").val(places['state']);
          $("#long").val(places['longitude']);
          $("#lat").val(places['latitude']);
          zip_box.addClass('success').removeClass('error');
        },
        error: function(result, success) {
          zip_box.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        }
      });
    }
});

});
function mapFunction() {

var mapOptions =
{
   // Set up the map options
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(),//coordinate should be from JSON results
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  zoom: 13,
};
var venueMap;                                      // Map() draws a map
venueMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript()
{
var script = document.createElement('script');     // Create <script> element
script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=mapFunction';
document.body.appendChild(script);                 // Add element to page
}

window.onload = loadScript;                          // on load call loadScript()

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".button").click(function()
  {
    $("#mapdiv").show(200);
  });
});


</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Enter Malaysian Zip Code</h3>

<div>
  <form action="#" method="post" class="form fancy-form">
    <div id="zipdiv">
      <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
      <input type="text" id="zcode" name="Zip code" placeholder="E.g : 48050">
    </div>

    <div id="citydiv">
      <label id="city_lbl" for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city">
  </div>

    <div id="statediv">
      <label id="state_lbl" for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" id="state" name="state">
    </div>

    <div id="longitudediv">
      <label id="lgtd_lbl" for="longitude">Longitude</label>
      <input type="text" id="long" name="longitude">
    </div>

    <div id="latitudediv">
      <label id="lttd_lbl" for="latitude">Latitude</label>
      <input type="text" id="lat" name="latitude">
    </div>

    <button id="button" class="button" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
    <div id="mapdiv">Map here: <div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div></div>


</form>


</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is one of the many example of the JSON Result user can get from Zippopotam.us :

> {"post code": "01000", 
>      "country": "Malaysia", 
>      "country abbreviation": "MY", 
>      "places": [{"place name": "Kangar", "longitude": "100.2056", "state": "Perlis", 
>     "state abbreviation": "PLS", "latitude": "6.4312"}]}

Another example :

> {"post code": "48050", "country": "Malaysia", "country abbreviation": "MY", "places": [{"place name": "Rawang", "longitude": "101.5642", "state": "Selangor", "state abbreviation": "SGR", "latitude": "3.2559"}]}

My programme should take the value of latitude and longitude from these results to be inserted to

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude here, longitude here),
//coordinate should be from JSON results the user get
```

The problem is, I've tried many ways, but it seems that I can't put the latitude and longitude from the JSON result to the above code (except from writing the numbers manually, but that's not how this programme supposed to work).

The programme should take the latitude and longitude value, and insert it automatically to the above code, so that when the user click the Submit button, a Google map is generated from that coordinates.

How do I solve this? Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initialization of the map into the the `.show` complete function for the `mapDiv`, so it executes *after* the map has a size and the success function of the `$.ajax` call has run and populated the value of the `places` object:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".button").click(function()
  {
    $("#mapdiv").show(200, function() { 
      mapFunction();
    });
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8Lrf5ad8/)

[jQuery `.show` function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

> ### .show( [duration ] [, complete ] )
>
> ---
>
> **duration** (default: 400)
>   Type: Number or String
>   A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> ---
>
> **complete**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

Comment: Oh my god, it works! Thank you. I never thought I can put mapFunction() inside .show() Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(places['latitude'], places['longitude']); //from your response
venueMap.setCenter(myLatLng);
```

If you want to animate transition, use

```
venueMap.panTo(myLatLng);
```

Consider checking [Google Maps JavaScript API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

Comment: Okay, I already tried it. It doesn't work. The part where the map becomes blank. But still, thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); can solve your problem since you initialize your map while your div is hidden.